# What reasons are there to dock a dog's tail?

Tags: dogs, health, docking

In relation to this question [Are there any behavioral or health issues related to docked dogs?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1257/are-there-any-behavioral-or-health-issues-related-to-docked-dogs).

Apart from cosmetic reasons, what reasons are there to dock a dog's tail?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [AMVA FAQ](https://www.avma.org/KB/Resources/FAQs/Pages/Frequently-asked-questions-about-canine-tail-docking.aspx)

> Removal of a dog’s tail for medical reasons is not referred to as
>   “docking.” The most common reason for amputation or partial amputation
>   of a dog’s tail is traumatic injury where repair of the entire tail is
>   not possible or advisable. Amputation may also occur in the case of
>   tail deformities that negatively impact a dog’s function or increase
>   risk of injury. An argument might be made for removal of the tail of a
>   dog on the basis of repeated prior injury.

So there are times where a dogs tail will be removed for medical reasons.

> Precautionary removal of the tail of a young puppy needs to be based
>   on compelling evidence that the animal is at high risk of tail trauma
>   due to congenital defect, breed and/or planned working activity.
>   However, such a justification must be supported by evidence such as
>   empirical data or impartial expert opinion based on extensive,
>   directly relevant experience.

And there are times where a dogs health will be affected as it grows up.
[For more on that](http://helenathegreat.hubpages.com/hub/CropDock):

> Dogs with "happy tail" have the potential to actually break their
>   tails by wagging them too hard and whacking something hard. This is
>   extremely painful for them, and often results in having to have their
>   tails docked as adults, which is much more painful than if it had been
>   done when they were days old.
>
> There is also the issue of the working dog, which is rare in today's
>   society, but certainly still exists. Herding breeds like Australian
>   Shepherds could get their tails stuck in a gate closing behind
>   livestock, and hunting breeds could get their tails stuck in thick
>   underbrush. Both of these situations would be terrible, and proponents
>   of tail docking argue that working English Pointers and Setters (whose
>   tails are not docked) suffer pain and infected tails because of this.

That is not to say that if a dog fits into this category it should automatically have its tail removed.  A hunter who goes out a few times a year with the dog is far less likely to lead to a tail injury than one who is out practically everyday.  As pointed in the original question the tail is an important part of the dog and **it should only be removed if it is actually necessary.**