# Do Boxers have a tendency towards Cherry-eye and gland-expression issues?

Tags: dogs, health, vision, genetics

My question is just what's in the title. I was under the impression that Boxers were one of the type of dogs that have that [gland](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anal_gland) near their anus that can cause them serious discomfort, as well as frequently getting [Cherry Eye](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cherry_eye).

Also, feel free to correct me if I'm wrong, but my understanding is that a select few breeds have these issues quite commonly, where many other breeds rarely if at all have these problems. If that's an inaccurate portrayal please tell me as such and I'll accept that answer.

Comment: Many breeds have anal gland issues; [here](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/549/how-can-i-prevent-my-dogs-from-scooting/559#559) are the steps to resolving that problem.

Comment: @JoshDM I'm familiar that it's not uncommon and there's a solution; thing is I'd rather choose a breed that is known not to have that issue, if as I say in my question it's per-dog and not a per-breed trait then please correct me

Comment: From research, I found [this](http://www.ehow.com/about_5080117_eye-problems-boxer-dog.html). It says boxers are more prone to eye problems

Answer (score 2):

Yes, according to [this source](http://pets.thenest.com/eye-problems-boxer-dog-6138.html) boxers are more likely than other breeds to suffer from cherry eye.

Further, [this comment](http://forums.thebump.com/post/quote/8982321/Comment_73848664) (full thread [here](http://forums.thebump.com/discussion/8982321/dog-anal-gland-problems?scrollreply=1#Form_Comment)) confirms that boxers are one of a few breeds that may need their anal glands expressed in-order to avoid dis-comfort.