# How can I help my Staffie who seems to have an itch in his bum?

Tags: dogs, health

My [Staffie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Staffordshire_Bull_Terrier) moves his bum around on the couch like he has an itch or something.

We have given him de-worming pills, but he still continues to try and scratch it - albeit very unsuccessfully.

Do you have any advice on what I can do?

EDIT: Thanks, I read through [How can I stop my dogs from scooting / dragging their butts?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/549/how-can-i-stop-my-dogs-from-scooting-dragging-their-butts) and it was very helpful although I don't think I have the stomach to do it myself.

Thanks all, this site is very helpful!

Comment: Have you taken him to the vet?

Comment: Perhaps this is relevant: http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/549/how-can-i-stop-my-dogs-from-scooting-dragging-their-butts

Comment: @DriesGroblerJr - as noted in the answer on the scooting/dragging question, you can always pay your vet or a groomer to do it.

Comment: Definitely take him to the vet - I took mine once and he barely has the problem anymore.